# Redux dispatch triggering, but store not updated

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

I've got a bunch of actions that all work except for one. The setFriend function runs but for some reason it never makes a call to reducer and therefore the store does not update.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    actions: {
      authenticate: (userId, password, handler) => {
        dispatch(AuthActions.authenticate(userId, password, handler));
      },
      register: (userId, password, userName, handler) => {
        dispatch(AuthActions.register(userId, password, userName, handler));
      },
      updateGotUserSuccess: (user, isSuccess) => {
        dispatch(AuthActions.updateGotUserSuccess(user, isSuccess));
      },
      setFriend: (friend)  => {
        debugger;
        dispatch(FriendsActions.setFriend(friend));
      }
    }
  };
}
```

All the functions listed above work, except setFriend which is the problem function. But when I debug, as shown below, it hits my first debugger but not the second one after the call to dispatch.

```
static setFriend(friend){
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({type: FriendsActions.GOT_FRIEND_SUCCESS, payload: friend});
    };
  }
```

This is my reducer

```
export default function getFriendReducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case FriendsActions.GOT_FRIEND_SUCCESS:
      debugger;
      return ObjUtils.cloneObj(action.payload);
    case FriendsActions.GOT_FRIEND_FAIL:
      debugger;
      return ObjUtils.cloneObj(action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

}

Comment: May or may not be the issue but it's worth the try... double check the `FriendsActions` and make sure the they both match in the reducer as well. Sometimes a misspelled constant string won't trigger a reducer.

Comment: Good point. But I did check that and besides my reducer never even get's called.

Comment: I've not got it but it has something to do with the redux-immutable-state-invariant plugin. Even if I use Object.assign({}, state ....) it still does not work.

Comment: Do you mind posting the component you're using 'setFriend' in?